# How to skip incompatible libraries in a qmake project?

Tags: qt, qmake

I am developing a Qt 5.3.1 GUI application to run on imx6 processor (ARM architecture) which works fine when I run it on the real target. Now, I wanted to build and run the GUI application stand alone on my desktop machine running Ubuntu.

I am able to compile properly, but just about to deploy the final executable I am noticing the below errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../target/usr/lib/foo.so when searching for -lfoo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
```

Am referencing some functions from this shared library in my Qt files so I cant remove the library from .pro file. 
I added below code in my .pro file to reference the above library

```
QMAKE_LIBS += -lfoo
QMAKE_LIBDIR += ../../target/usr/lib/
```

Am running on kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 GCC 32 bit, using Qt Creator 3.1.2.

The library what I am trying to link was compiled on imx6 32 bit compiler.

Comment: maybe you need to build a fake foo.so, if the library isn't available

Comment: I have the library file in the path mentioned.

Comment: what I mean: seems you have to recompile it with your current process architecture

Comment: What is the mkspec of your target?

Comment: Thanks @CapelliC - I re-compiled my library source with i686 pc linux gnu and my problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`LIBS`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) variable to link the external library:

```
LIBS += -L./../target/usr/lib/ -lfoo
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the target-specific libraries conditionally depending on the mkspec. Say, if you had windows-only libraries, you'd add `win32: LIBS += ....` to the project file.

You'd need to add conditional compilation to your code and/or project file to disable compiling the code that uses the library unavailable on the desktop. Alternatively, add a source that has a dummy implementation of your library - only compile the source for your target.

You also shouldn't be using `QMAKE_...` variables unless you have a specific reason - they are qmake's implementation details. Use `LIBS` and `LIBDIR` directly.